# How to track beta testing usage for android app I built?

Tags: android

Is there any service that can be used to monitor how a beta-user engages in an android application I made?

I've looked into different analytic solutions, but they all come with the disclaimer that I should not send "unique identification information about the users" - fair enough, and I can appreciate the privacy concerns. But I need to dig that information during my beta testing.

Currently, I'm emailing the apk files to a few people to install the app and test on their phones. They give me feedback, but not all of them are good at describing exactly what they are doing. I need more detailed information - like how they opened the app (was it a fresh open, or did they relaunch it from the running app list?), what exactly they did in the app and if possible, to get some debugging information too, since some issues are unique to the specific model of phone they use.

In a nutshell, it means that I need to dig into my beta-testers devices - and they all agree to it too, so its not like I'm spying on them or some such. (At the very least, I want to record their behavior in my app with permission)

Is anything like this available? If not, are there any other approaches I can use to solve/debug issues that generate from end-user behavior? (NOTE: I'm not talking about app crashing/hanging. The app is stable - its just not working correctly)

**Stuff that doesn't seem to work:**

- http://acra.ch/

This looks more like a crash reporting tool than a usage/monitoring tool. :(

- http://try.crashlytics.com/

Similar issues to above

Answer (score 0):

Paid levels of BugSense come with a feature called Bread Crumbs, which I've never used but which sound like what you need.